# how to fill combo box in silverlight from database

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have a silverlight application.In this i have used service file for DML operations.The methods in Service can be accesed in form page.ie the the XAML page(example Main.XAML)
MY issue is i cant access my DB in the XAML pages as it is in silverlight,i want to create a method in Service file,get some data from MAster tables and fill it in the combo boxes which are there in my first form.
Im trying to use System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox combobox as a control as i cant access the controls of my forms in the service file and then trying to use this control in my form(Main.xaml)then it is showing an error.

Can anyone please let me know how can i populate data this way in combo box.
Rply as early as posible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an operation to your service that returns a collection of data contracts (for instance a collection of products).

Then call the service from your SL application using an asynchronous call and bind the data to the combo box in the async callback.

There's a working example [here](http://www.getdotnetcode.com/nexDotNet/020037/020037.htm).

Comment: Can i get the same for C#...Silverlight4,VS2010..or for atleast C#

Comment: how can i write this code in c#                                       Public Function GetCountries() As List(Of Country)
        Dim db As New LightSpeedClassesDataContext
        Return (From c In db.Countries Select c).ToList
    End Function

Comment: This is the code you have to write in your service. Then you can invoke the operation from your SL client via a proxy (Add service reference).

Comment: yup i have services references added to my app...i want the code in c# can u convert it in C# please.it would be really great

Comment: Dim db As New LightSpeedClassesDataContext
        Return (From c In db.Countries Select c).ToList
This is what the syntax in C# is but with error.
 public  List<BranchMaster>GetBranch()
 {
            bool flag =false;
            BranchMaster db;
            return(from c in db.Name).ToList;
        }
its showing error after the closing bracket after Name thata query body must end wit ha select clause.
can u please correct

Comment: Thanks for ur rplies...
Im still getting an error when i write the code
 return (from c in db.Name select c).ToList

Cannot convert method ToListto NonDelegate type...

Comment: Hopefully u can sort out my issues tommorow if possible.